# Flutter - The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Response<dynamic>' Error Occurred

Tags: flutter, http, dio

```java
class Screen extends StatefulWidget {
  const Screen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Screen> createState() => _ScreenState();
}

class _ScreenState extends State<Screen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    requestUrl();
  }

  Future<dynamic> requestUrl() async {
    List<Response> response;
    var dio = Dio();
    var newsHome =
        'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=kr&apiKey=3e3d6c4106c84f27be6d9578970fc4e8';

    response = await Future.wait([
      dio.get(newsHome),
    ]);
    print(response[0]['articles']);
  }
```

```java
44:22: Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Response<dynamic>'.
 - 'Response' is from 'package:dio/src/response.dart' ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dio-4.0.6/lib/src/response.dart').
Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
    print(response[0]['articles']);
```

While doing http communication through the dio library,
the same error as in the code above occurred.
I've searched several places, but I'm not quite sure what the problem is. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use [data](https://pub.dev/documentation/dio/latest/dio/Response/data.html) on `Response` to access actual data. Something like this:

```
response[0].data['articles']
```